# MS SQL SERVER PAGING

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did a query which is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.logID 
FROM Monitor_data m 
inner join Monitor_object o on (o.objID = m.domainID)
inner join Monitor_event e on (e.mainID = m.logID)
WHERE (o.name = @objName
and m.service = @service
and e.statement = @statement
and m.start >= @start
and m.end <= @end)
```

That allows me to get some id (VARCHAR(50)). But, now I want to make a pagination  so I need to modify that query. Unfortunately, I cannot use LIMIT and OFFSET ... I may use ROW_NUMBER but I don't know how :/ It will be great to get a result corresponding to the rows at line n to m. Thus, I will be able to create a paging process easily.

Can someone help me ? 
Thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? `OFFSET` and `FETCH` were introduced in 2012. If you're running 2008R2, your priority right now should be migrating off it anyway since it'll be out of support entirely in a year.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2012. Thank you for your answer, indeed, OFFSET and FETCH  work. But I used to work with PostgreSQL and MYSQL, when I said LIMIT and OFFSET I mean using a such query : SELECT toto FROM babar LIMIT .. OFFSET ... (PostgreSQL) knowing with mysql LIMIT allows to do it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select logID from (
    SELECT DISTINCT m.logID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by m.start) rn
    FROM Monitor_data m 
    inner join Monitor_object o on (o.objID = m.domainID)
    inner join Monitor_event e on (e.mainID = m.logID)
    WHERE (o.name = @objName
           and m.service = @service
           and e.statement = @statement
           and m.start >= @start
           and m.end <= @end)
) a where rn between (m, n) --here you provide values for limits for rows to return
```

Above query is based on `ROW_NUMBER` function in SQL Server, which requires some ordering, so I assumed that `m.start` will provide an order (I think it start date or something :) ).

Comment: Exactly ! m.start is indeed a start date :)  But I use another key to order it ;) Thank you.

Comment: @Simba OK, do as you like :) Also accept the answer if it has helped you (and optionally upvote).

Answer (score 3):

Use `@PageIndex` and `PageSize` for paging

```
declare @PageIndex int=1
declare @PageSize int=10
declare @RecordCount int
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.logID ) as RowNumber, DISTINCT m.logID 
INTO #Results
FROM Monitor_data m 
    inner join Monitor_object o on (o.objID = m.domainID)
    inner join Monitor_event e on (e.mainID = m.logID)
WHERE (o.name = @objName
    and m.service = @service
    and e.statement = @statement
    and m.start >= @start
    and m.end <= @end)

SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results

SELECT 
    *, @RecordCount as RecordCount  FROM #Results 
WHERE  
        RowNumber BETWEEN (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
Select logId from 
(SELECT DISTINCT m.logID, Row_number() over (order by (select null)) as ranking 
FROM Monitor_data m 
inner join Monitor_object o on (o.objID = m.domainID)
inner join Monitor_event e on (e.mainID = m.logID)
WHERE (o.name = @objName
and m.service = @service
and e.statement = @statement
and m.start >= @start
and m.end <= @end))
where ranking between n and m
```

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY ******

OFFSET @ItemsPerPage * (@CurrentPage - 1) ROWS

FETCH NEXT @ItemsPerPage ROWS ONLY

```
DECLARE @CurrentPage int = 1;
DECLARE @ItemsPerPage int = 10;

SELECT DISTINCT m.logID 
FROM Monitor_data m 
inner join Monitor_object o on (o.objID = m.domainID)
inner join Monitor_event e on (e.mainID = m.logID)
WHERE (o.name = @objName
and m.service = @service
and e.statement = @statement
and m.start >= @start
and m.end <= @end)


ORDER BY m.logID

OFFSET @ItemsPerPage * (@CurrentPage - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @ItemsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

paging Example

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(Id int, Name nvarchar(50),EventDate date);

INSERT INTO @myTable(Id, Name, EventDate)
VALUES (1, 'a', '2018-01-01'),
(2, 'b', '2018-01-02'),
(3, 'c', '2018-01-03'),
(4, 'd', '2018-01-04'),
(5, 'e', '2018-01-05'),
(6, 'f', '2018-01-06');


DECLARE @CurrentPage int = 1;
DECLARE @ItemsPerPage int = 4;


SELECT * FROM @myTable
ORDER BY EventDate  DESC
OFFSET @ItemsPerPage * (@CurrentPage - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @ItemsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: That's perfect !  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 2012, you could use OFFSET and FETCH. Prior to that a  solution is to use ROW_NUMBER. However, beware, ROW_NUMBER() approach is very slow. If you don't have a performance problem you can use it.

Whatever the version is, a fast paging is done using TOP N and ordering by your desired columns and also specifying minimum value. ie:

```
select TOP (@pageSize) * from myTable
where myKeyValue > @minValue
order by myKeyValue;
```